# PyCharm / OS X El Capitan / Python 3.5.2 - matplotlib not working in script

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pycharm

Python noob here, apologies if this is has an obvious answer I should know. I'm using Python 3.5.2 via PyCharm in OSX El Capitan and I'm trying to run the following simple script to practise with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
year = [1950,1970,1990,2010]
pop = [2.159,3.692,5.263,6.972]
plt.plot(year,pop)
plt.show()
```

If I execute this line by line in PyCharm's Python console, it works fine. If I execute it as an entire script, I get this error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5/Users/Cuckoo/Dropbox/Python/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Cuckoo/Dropbox/Python/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone please explain what has gone wrong and better still, how I can fix it?

Comment: I would suggest to open a terminal and run `python3 /Users/Cuckoo/Dropbox/Python/test.py` to check if `Random` is already installed or not. If not, you need to install it by using pip (or pip3). But, if you got no error, it means that the python that your pycharm uses does not recognize this package. Sometimes a simple restart of pycharm works. Sometimes you need to change the location of python in your pycharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by having another Python script in your project named `random.py` that is overriding the original library named Random.

Try to rename or remove the `random.py` file and your script should work from within PyCharm and the command line.

Comment: I can reproduce the exact problem and error message by creating a random.py file in my project.

Comment: This. Exactly this. Thank you.